# Bringing (outdoor) food to Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, food-and-drink

In august I will go to Japan to visit relatives and to make a trekking. In europe I usualy bring trekking meals with me, the kind of meals that you can easily prepare on a stove by just adding water.

Those meals are sealed in plastic and usually look like this:

[image]

I've never had any problems in Europe, but when I look up the regulations on traveling to Japan, I read various restriction, ranging from not being allowed to bring in any meat products, up onto dissolowence of milk, vegetable or egg products.

I could live without meat (there are vegetarian meals available), but the other ingredients would be a problem.

Does anyone have experience with bringing food into japan?

Comment: Yes, I mixed it up a little, first posted on "the great outdoors", where I was asked to ask it here.

A while later, the question on "the great outdoors" was moved here, so now it's a duplicate here.